# UIPanGestureRecognizer + UIViewController

Tags: ios, uipangesturerecognizer

I am adding a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to a partially hidden `UIViewController` (it is there to pull it back on screen). All is working fine except on the odd occasion when the `UIViewController` has a scrollable subView (i.e. `UIScrollView`, `UITableView`). I can't set `useInteractionEnabled = NO` because this disables my gesture... Any suggested workarounds?

**EDIT:**

I have this work around and it is achieving what I want...

```
for(UIView *subView in sender.view.subviews) {

    [subView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
}
```

But I feel there should be a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I have come up with is

```
for(UIView *subView in sender.view.subviews) {

    [subView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
}
```